# How to hide dynamic content with php?

Tags: php

i was wandering how i could hide content of a page based on the page you are located , i did this with the code from below , however i was wondering how i could hide a page that is generated dynamically for example index.php**?id=......**.

Is there a php function that i could use that would say disregard all that is after .php so don't take into consideration ?id=.. .

```
if($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] != "/3uboats/index.php"){

CONTENT TO HIDE 

}
```

If i was not clear plz ask for clarification , thanks all in advance

i want to hide content for this page **stampa_fattura_partenza.php?id_prenotazione_partenze=1** the 1 is generated by php , its dynamic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should better not use `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` that is insecure. You could check if a variable is set by this code:

```
if(isset($_GET['id_prenotazione_partenze']) &&
         $_GET['id_prenotazione_partenze'] != 1) {
    ...
}
```

This should work for your example.

Comment: i cant add variables for this control because iam using a master page with obstart so this code is loded before the variable with the code loads

Comment: I don't understand how this is related to obstart. Could you explain that? If you just want to check that the variable `id_prenotazione_partenze` is set you could use just the first part: `if(isset($_GET['id_prenotazione_partenze']))`

Comment: working like a charm , thanks mate by the way it has nothing to do with ob start , Thanks a bunch

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is get the value of your id using $_REQUEST["id_prenotazione_partenze"] or $_GET["id_prenotazione_partenze"] and use that in your php IF.

```
if($_REQUEST["id_prenotazione_partenze"]==1){
    // HIDE
}
```

This hides content when your page id = 1 for example.

Comment: `$_REQUEST` is not the best option better use `$_GET` or `$_POST`.

Comment: I have gotten myself into that argument with numerous programmers before. There is no real difference in performance, and I think REQUEST is easier for new programmers. Like to know your reasons for choosing GET

Comment: It is like registed globals. It can happen that a variable that shoule be only set be post is setted by get. In some conditions you may open your script XSS attacks.

Comment: @rekire $_REQEUST is much more stable. If you want to avoid XSS attacks - better work on your request parsing and disable evaluation of passed script.

Comment: Sometimes I feel there is no real answer to this feud :) Or we should make another topic about it :D

Comment: Well you are right it depends on the application. I personally prefer `$_GET` and `$_POST` so I know exactly what I will get. I uses get because that one is related to the question above.

Answer (score 1):

You can check whether `$_REQUEST[ "id_prenotazione_partenze" ]` is set, like:

```
if( isset( $_REQUEST[ "id_prenotazione_partenze" ] ) ){
//hide content
}
```

Then if any value is passed with `$_REQUEST[ "id_prenotazione_partenze" ]` it will evaluate the `if` statement.

Comment: @rekire Thanks for noticing typos +)